# Chiral carbons in glucose

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

In the open chain structure of glucose, one can identify 4 chiral carbon atoms but some sources consider the ring structure and then say that glucose has 5 chiral carbon atoms. If asked to state the number of chiral carbon atoms in glucose, which case should I consider?

Comment: Well, it seems you have answered yourself. It depends.

Comment: On a mcq test (single option correct type) I was asked this question. It simply said " How many chiral carbons are present in beta D-(+)-glucose? " and there were options for both 4 and 5. What to choose now?

Comment: That Greek letter descriptor, "beta" (should be written as: β) is a game changer. It indicates that in fact it's an anomer, i.e. one of cyclic forms, and has 5 chiral carbon atoms.

Comment: To elaborate on @mykhal 's comment, the $\beta$ symbol indicates that we are talking about the *Haworth Structure* of glucose, which is commonly called the the cyclic structure of glucose.

Comment: @Firefox1921 To be precise, there's not "Haworth structure", it's a type of projection formula, β is related to the stereochemical configuration, and the "ordinary" structure formula is maybe somewhat more helpful, in the context of natural compounds nomenclature α/β stereodescriptors meaning.

Comment: Yes @mykhal, I meant that. My mistake! Sorry!

Comment: @Firefox1921 up vote for mature response to critique